# Why is my Entity Manager returning empty ResultLists?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm having quite the predicament with my Web Application.

For my school project, we have to migrate from classical JDBC Integration to a JPA Integration. As for myself, I've decided to use Hibernate JPA Framework. I've tried in a main inside a SessionBean, it works there. But whenever I integrate it in a Web Servlet, I noticed it returned empty lists. I've tried displaying the size of the lists with `System.out.println()`.

Anyways, I *think* the problem might be in my `persistence.xml`, more specifically the lack of a `<jta-data-source>something here</jta-data-source>` in it.

Here's my `persistence.xml`, maybe you could see where I'm having issues :

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>JavaBeans.Employee</class>
    <class>JavaBeans.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEEPRJ?serverTimezone=Europe/Paris"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jee"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="jee"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.serverTimezone" value="Europe/Paris"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.useSSL" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here's my Session Bean for Employee :

```
package SessionBeans;

import JavaBeans.Employee;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 */
@Stateless
public class EmployeeSB {

    @PersistenceContext(name="PERSISTENCE")
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){

        String query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e ";
        Query q  = em.createQuery(query);
        List<Employee> employees = q.getResultList();
        if(employees!=null){
            System.out.println("it's not null list size : " + q.getResultList().size());
            for(Employee emp:employees){
                System.out.println("id  : " + emp.getId());
            }
            return employees;
        }
        System.out.println("it's null");
        return employees;
    }
```

And my Employee class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer id;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "NOM")
    public String nom;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "PRENOM")
    public String prenom;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "TELDOMICILE")
    public String telDomicile;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "TELPORTABLE")
    public String telPortable;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "TELPRO")
    public String telPro;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "ADRESSE")
    public String adresse;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CODEPOSTAL")
    public String codePostal;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "VILLE")
    public String ville;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    public String email;


    public Employee() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getTelDomicile() {
        return telDomicile;
    }

    public void setTelDomicile(String telDomicile) {
        this.telDomicile = telDomicile;
    }

    public String getTelPortable() {
        return telPortable;
    }

    public void setTelPortable(String telPortable) {
        this.telPortable = telPortable;
    }

    public String getTelPro() {
        return telPro;
    }

    public void setTelPro(String telPro) {
        this.telPro = telPro;
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }

    public String getCodePostal() {
        return codePostal;
    }

    public void setCodePostal(String codePostal) {
        this.codePostal = codePostal;
    }

    public String getVille() {
        return ville;
    }

    public void setVille(String ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }





    public Employee(String nom, String prenom, String telDomicile, String telPortable, String telPro, String adresse, String codePostal, String ville, String email) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.telDomicile = telDomicile;
        this.telPortable = telPortable;
        this.telPro = telPro;
        this.adresse = adresse;
        this.codePostal = codePostal;
        this.ville = ville;
        this.email = email;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Employee)) {
            return false;
        }
        Employee other = (Employee) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JavaBeans.Employee[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

(Don't mind the French haha).

Anyways, if somebody sees why the entity manager is returning empty lists, that would help me a lot and make me understand where I made my stupid mistake.

Thanks a lot guys and have a great day,

Fares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find where the issue is. Buckle up for the ride cause it's gonna be a long one.

In my `persistence.xml` I never got to define a `<jta-data-source></jta-data-source>` because I didn't understand it's goal and why we needed to use it.

Since then I have developed a large amount of knowledge and wisdom (not really, basically trial-and-error philosophy).

So. Enough talking. Straight to the answer.

As I said previously the `<jta-data-source></jta-data-source>` wasn't defined in the `persistence.xml` in lieu of a huge `<properties></properties>` section.

Netbeans IDE generates a file in the WEB-INF folder of your directory. It's called `glassfish-resources.xml`. Our `persistence.xml` is somewhat binded to it. In the resources file, we define all of our JDBC connection properties. We name it in a pool through a JNDI.

Therefore our new `persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="m1se_appv2_war_1.0PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/DBJEE</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the (in)famous glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_JEEPRJ_jeePool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="JEEPRJ"/>
        <property name="User" value="jee"/>
        <property name="Password" value="***"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JEEPRJ?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=Europe/Paris"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/DBJEE" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_JEEPRJ_jeePool"/>
</resources>
```

**BTW If you are using MySQL version above 5.7, absolutely define the useSSL property in URL preferably as false if you don't intend to use it.**

Answer (score 0):

If you copy/paste the same code of the above session bean inside the servlet, be careful about transaction management. Since session beans manage transactions as their default behavior, as you did you have not to manage them in the beans. However servlets don't have such this behavior, and it's your own responsibility to implement them.

Be notice that it would be an anti-pattern to implement database related jobs inside servlets which belongs to the view layer. The better approach is using session beans for such this functionality and just call them inside the view layer.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad.
I am using a Session Bean for my DB operations. The problem is I can't seem to get results from these operations...

Comment: If you can retrieve data inside the session bean, you should be able to get the same result inside the servlet by calling that session bean. Are you sure, you do the same as you explaining? If so, I need to see some more details of your code.

Comment: That's the problem though, I can't retrieve data in my Session Beans... However if I create manually the Entity Manager through an Entity Manager Factory in a `public static void main()` and configure it piece by piece, I do receive data through the manually created Entity Manager.
The problem is the Entity Manager within the Session Bean isn't receiving the data.